# How to join table doctrine symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two table in my database and i want to join this 2 table to show data in my view but i didn't find a solution.

This is my first entity given below

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class classified   
{
     /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $classified_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    protected $user_id=0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
    protected $firstname="null";

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $region_id="null";
```

The second entity :

```
class regions  
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    protected $region_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
    protected $regionname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    protected $country_id=107;
}
```

In my controller i would like to join the table to get information.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()
                   ->getEntityManager();

        $classified = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->select('b')
                    ->from('BlogBundle:classified',  'b')
                    ->addOrderBy('b.classifiedaddeddate', 'DESC')
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
        return $this->render('BlogBundle:Page:index.html.twig', array(
            'classified' => $classified
        ));
```

Any solution please?

Comment: Your schema is incorrect. You should never ever write somethig_id in an entity. You bind objects togather by reference and not database ids. Please read through the documentation carefully.

Answer (score 6):

**Write beautiful & clean code,**

Before answering, I would suggest you fix the following issues in your code,

- Class name should be CamelCase & singular (`Classified` instead of `classified` and `Region` instead of `regions`)
- Try to find a cleaner way to set the `country_id` (as `protected $country_id=107;` doesn't make sens. Same for `user_id`)

---

**So,** in order to get your classified entity with its related region, you've to,

First, change (in your `Classified` class)

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $region_id="null";
```

to

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Region", inversedBy="classifieds")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="region_id", referencedColumnName="region_id")
 */
protected $region;
```

and add to your `Region` entity,

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Classified", mappedBy="region")
 */
protected $classifieds;
```

**Take a deeper look at** the [Entity Relationships/Associations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations) part of the [Databases and Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) chapter of the documentation to understand how to define entities associations using Doctrine.

Comment: You maybe meant `OneToMany(targetEntity="Classified", mappedBy="region")`

Comment: sorry i didn't  explain well my problem i have the table region full of information so i have to extract this information when i combine the two table (for exemple i like to get the variable $regionname when classified.region_id=region.region_id )

Comment: Yes, if your entities associations are well defined (as I suggested) getting regionname is as easy as doing,

$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
     ->select('c.*, r.regionname')
     ->from('classified c')
     ->leftJoin('c.region r')
     -> ...

Take your time to go deeper into the documentation in order to understand all the possible uses of doctrine associations.